# socket send() hangs after sending certain amount of bytes

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

I want to send a string to my nodejs TCP server.

This is the code for my client (C++):

```
#include <nds.h>
#include <dswifi9.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string>

std::string hostname = "hostname";
int port = 61733;
int sock;

int main(){
    Connect(); //function to connect with a WiFi network
    ConnectToServer();

    unsigned long lastSendTime = 0;
    unsigned long sendInterval = 200; //send a message every 200 milliseconds
    unsigned int nMsgSent = 0;

    while (1){
        unsigned long now = milliseconds(); //function to get the time in milliseconds
        if ((now - lastSendTime) > sendInterval){
            std::string request = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
            request += request;
            request += std::to_string(nMsgSent);
            request += "\n";

            int sendResult = ::send(sock, request.c_str(), request.length(), 0);
            iprintf("req(%d): %d\n", nMsgSent, sendResult);

            nMsgSent++;
            lastSendTime = now;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is my server code (JS):

```
var net = require('net');

var tcpServer = net.createServer();  
var tcpPort = 61733;

tcpServer.on('connection', onConnection);

function onConnection(conn){  
  var remoteAddress = conn.remoteAddress + ':' + conn.remotePort;
  console.log('New client connection from: %s', remoteAddress);

  conn.on('data', onData);
  conn.once('close', onClose);
  conn.on('error', onError);

  function onData(data){
    console.log('connection data from %s: %s', remoteAddress, data);
  }

  function onClose(){
    console.log('connection from %s closed', remoteAddress);
  }

  function onError(err){
    console.log('Connection %s error: %s', remoteAddress, err.message);
  }
}

tcpServer.listen(tcpPort, function(){  
  console.log('Server listening on: %j', tcpServer.address());
});
```

Here comes the problem:

The client only sends about 180 messages and then `send` hangs. The server only receives ~120 messages. When I increase the length of the request, the client sends less requests and when I decrease the length, the clients sends more requests. I also found out that when I decrease the sendInterval, I can send more requests before `send` hangs. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. When I execute similar code with a nodejs client, everything is okay, so the problem lies with the C++ client.

EDIT:

I don't really think this is necessary, but here is the code of `connectToServer()`:

```
void ConnectToServer()
{
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (socket >= 0)
    {
        printf("Created Socket!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Couldn't create socket");
    }

    struct hostent * host = gethostbyname(hostname.c_str());
    if (host != NULL)
    {
        printf("Found IP Address!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("IP not found");
    }   

    struct sockaddr_in server;
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(port);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = *((unsigned long *)(host->h_addr_list[0]));

    int connectResult = ::connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server));
    if (connectResult >= 0)
    {
        printf("Connected to server!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Not connected to server. Err: %d\n", connectResult);
    }   
}
```

Output from C++ client(send interval: 2000ms, msgLength: 126-127 chars):

```
req(1): 126
req(2: 126
req(3): 126
...keeps going on for a while...
req(9): 126
req(10): 126
req(11): 127
req(12): 127
...keeps going on for a while...
req(74): 64
send() hangs after this
```

Output from nodejs server(only receives 9 messages):

```
connection data from ip::port: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ12345678900

...keeps going on for a while...

connection data from ip::port: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ12345678909
```

Test results to see if there's a connection between send interval, message length and the number of sent messages:

```
 sendInterval |  msgLength  |   nMsg
---------------------------------------
     200      |    127      |    26
     200      |    65       |    33
---------------------------------------
     400      |    65       |    59
     400      |    127      |    53
---------------------------------------
     2000     |    65       |    47
     2000     |    127      |    21
```

(I don't see a connection between these values)

Comment: Don't spam tags! This is not C. C is not C++ is not C!

Comment: @Olaf I know, but the socket library is C code, right?

Comment: @user7353781 The language of the socket library is irrelevant to your question.

Comment: If the client sends messages faster than the server reads them, the client will eventually block until the server catches up. Are you sure the server is reading the messages?

Comment: As is almost every library you use at some level. Do you think the C tag should be added for **every** question?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, the server prints all the messages and I have the same problem with a greater send interval.

Comment: You say that the number of requests depends on the length. Is `num*length` about the same each time? What is that value?

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong in the code, you don't have to do anything special to use `send()`.

Comment: @Olaf, no I'm sorry, but you changed it. Could you please remove your downvote? I'm just a beginner and it's really frustrating when questions get downvoted because of these things. In this way, people will probably not even see my question. Thanks for improving my question though.

Comment: Does `ConnectToServer()` set any socket options?

Comment: @Barmar Nope, `ConnectToServer()` doesn't set any socket options. This is the code of `ConnectToServer()`: https://pastebin.com/Ki29xpY9

Comment: @Barmar I don't see a connection between `sendInterval`, `num` and `length`. Here are my test results: https://pastebin.com/RFBP8dXt

Comment: @user7353781: 1) ssuming a commenter is also a downvoter is a bad assumption. 2) I don't downvote for wrong tags. At least if the OP accepts the removal like you do. (Starting a rollback war about tags could change my mind, though). 3) Your question has other issues.

Comment: @Olaf My question had only 3 views, 1 downvote and you edited my question, so I assumed you were the downvoter. My apologies if you weren't the downvoter. Does my question still have that other issues you're talking about? If so, what issues do you mean?

Comment: From the [NodeJS documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html): "*Attaching a listener for the 'data' event, ... will switch `readable._readableState.flowing` to true, causing the Readable to begin actively emitting events as data is generated... receiving "back pressure" will cause the `readable._readableState.flowing` to be set as false, **temporarily halting the flowing of events** but not halting the generation of data... While `readable._readableState.flowing` is false, **data may be accumulating within the streams internal buffer**.*"

Comment: Perhaps your server is experiencing ["back pressure"](http://engineering.voxer.com/2013/09/16/backpressure-in-nodejs/), thus cutting off your `onData` event handler?

Comment: Can you, please, attach the output generated by the `iprintf("req(%d): %d\n", nMsgSent, sendResult);` statement in the client?  It may help to understand what's going on.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I don't think so. I can send the same data to the server with a send interval of 100ms without problems, but when I send that data to the server with a send interval of 2000ms with my C++ client, I get this problem.

Answer (score 0):

As i can see there are some issues that you should attend:

1. You are trying to send many message into the while of the client's
   code, but you are not checking if there is an error, using the
   variable `sendResult` . It should be checked before send another
   message.
2. You are using the same thread to send data and check for the interval which has an infinity loop to send each message, it consume a lot of CPU. I suggest to create a thread (*TSync*) to attend the interval with `sleep` or `std::chrono`  and invoke a method which send the message by socket, but not in the same thread *TSync* because you will block socket with sleeps.
3. Finally, you should use `FD_SET` and `select`to check when you can send data by sockets, when the socket is ready to send more bytes.

**It is probably that the way you are sending message without control is afecting the TX channel because it is getting fulled** so you should control the output operation with `FD_SET` and `select` to get synchronized with the socket. In the case of write, [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141(v=vs.85).aspx) says:

> The select function is used to determine the status of one or more sockets. For each socket, the caller can request information on read, write, or error status.
>
> **writefds**: Data can be sent.

**UPDATED, April 21th**: I suggest you share more information about your problem, like the code and configuration of your server to know if there is some time out configured or buffer size. The information that you are supplied is not enough and don't understimated the request that us make you, like this comment:

> I don't really think this is necessary, but here is the code of connectToServer():

The connection process is important because we can see if the socket server has some options setted.

In this case all information that you shared us could be helpful instead of assume that is not important.

So, at this moment, that is all that i can help you.

**UPDATE April 24th**: Try these steps to control the socket transmition and setting a **NON-Blocing** socket:

- After you get a successful connection, in the client, set the socket as NON-BLOCKING.
- Use in your loop File Descriptor (`FD_SET`) and `select` to check when the socket is ready to write.

Your code should has a code as follow:

```
void ConnectToServer()
{
    //... your code

    int connectResult = ::connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server));
    if (connectResult >= 0)
    {
        u_long iMode = 1;
        int iResult = ioctlsocket(sock, FIONBIO, &iMode); //Set the socket Non-Blocking

        printf("Connected to server!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Not connected to server. Err: %d\n", connectResult);
    }
}

int main(){
    Connect(); //function to connect with a WiFi network
    ConnectToServer();

    unsigned long lastSendTime = 0;
    unsigned long sendInterval = 200; //send a message every 200 milliseconds
    unsigned int nMsgSent = 0;


    fd_set write_fd;

    while (1){
        unsigned long now = milliseconds(); //function to get the time in milliseconds
        if ((now - lastSendTime) > sendInterval){
            std::string request = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
            request += request;
            request += std::to_string(nMsgSent);
            request += "\n";

            FD_ZERO(&write_fd); //Reset the File Descriptor
            FD_SET(sock, &write_fd); //Set se File descriptor to the socket.

            int result = select(max_sd, NULL, &write_fd, NULL, NULL);   //Wait until the socket is ready to write

            if (result < 0)
            {
                iprintf("There was a problem with the sockets reading.\n");
                FD_ZERO(&write_fd);
            }

            int sendResult = ::send(sock, request.c_str(), request.length(), 0);
            iprintf("req(%d): %d\n", nMsgSent, sendResult);

            nMsgSent++;
            lastSendTime = now;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work :( The `send()` doesn't return any errors (I log the result of `send()` and everything seems fine). I can't use multithreading, because my target doesn't support that. I tried to use `FD_SET` and `select`, but that doesn't work.

Comment: @user7353781  Can you change the protocol? If you can you should implement an ANK Message to sinchronize  each transmition and its reception. But i don't know if you can do it in your program.

Comment: No, I want to use tcp.

Comment: The code of my server has already been included in my question, but the problem lies with the c++ client, because the nodejs client works perfectly with my server.

Comment: @user7353781, a added a sample of how you can use Nonblocking socket and `select`in your code.

Comment: 2 questions: Can I use `ioctl()` instead of `ioctlsocket()`? `ioctlsocket()` is not available at my target system. Also, where comes `max_sd` from? Is it a constant maybe? It's not available at my target system.

And I might be wrong, but it seems like you're using Windows sockets, but my target system runs Linux.

Comment: For Linux you should use `fcntl `.

Comment: Using your example with `ioctl()` instead of `ioctlsocket()` and '1' instead of `max_sd` doesn't work btw.

Comment: use something like this: `int flags = fcntl(socketTx,F_GETFL);`  `flags = (flags & ~O_NONBLOCK);` `nRet = fcntl(socketTx,F_SETFL,flags);`

Comment: Still doesn't work :( Also, it doesn't throw any errors.

Comment: Add these options at your socket, after it is connected: To set the TimeOut to Send (`SO_SNDTIMEO`), to Set the Transmiton Buffer size (SO_SNDBUF). This could hep you to raise an error in your program. Also i considere use another options, check this link: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html. A sample to add this options is: `int tout = 2000; ` `setsockopt(socketTx,SOL_SOCKET,SO_RCVTIMEO, (const char*)&tout,sizeof(int));`.